# Can I use standard deviation in Likert scale (1-7) data with non normal distribution?

Tags: nonparametric, standard-deviation, likert

I have 20 questions, each divided in 6 Likert scale items (1-7), representing 6 different values like Success, Oportunity, etc. The sample is rather small, 42 cases, and the distribution is not normal.

Basically, I want to compare responses to values between individuals in certain groups consisting of 4-5 individuals, and see how much do the responses differ for each value within these mini-groups.

Is it ok to use standard deviation? 
Please suggest any nonparametric tests that might be more suitable for this analysis.
Any reccomandation is welcome!

Comment: Welcome to the site.
Do you mean that you actually have 120 questions? (6 Likert scales times 20 questions?) If so, how are you combining them into 20 questions?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Actually I have 120 variables in my spss file. For each question, the person had to rate (from 1 to 7) six different Values (~ A principle, standard, or quality considered worthwhile or desirable).

Answer (score 2):

If you add 20 Likert items (not technically exactly correct to do, but often done anyway) then the resulting sum can take so many values that you can probably treat it as continuous and do t-tests, using the Satterthwaite correction for unequal variances if needed. Or, if you want to compare more than two groups at a time, you can do regression or ANOVA

However, if each group has 4 or 5 people, it is going to be very hard to find statistically significant differences. The effect size would have to be very large.

Comment: I was thinking about summing them up, I will try that up. But, the problem is that I'm not interested in comparing groups with each other; I just want to check the cohesion inside a group -unfortunately, very small.

Comment: Then you have to define "cohesion". You wrote
"Basically, I want to compare responses to values between individuals in certain groups consisting of 4-5 individuals, and see how much do the responses differ for each value within these mini-groups"

But I don't understand what it means. What is "comparing responses to values"?

Comment: Well, by cohesion I mean social cohesion: The bonds that bring people together in a given society; while by value: A principle, standard, or quality considered worthwhile or desirable.
Hope that makes it clear. I am sorry for the confusion!